# Creating reverse proportion in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with creating a excel formula. I have a set of numbers in column A and I need a formula in cell B1 that would return:

1. 100 if A1 is the lowest number in column A
2. 0 if A1 is the largest number in column A
3. proportional number if it is in between (e.g. 50 if it is half way between largest and lowest number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=(A1-MIN(A:A))/(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))*100
```

[image]

Comment: As I said I need it in reverse so in your example B1 would be 0 and B24 would be 100 altough if I put =100-(A1-MIN(A:A))/(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))*100 it shoud do the work. Thanks :)